# Add annotation using map quest.

Tags: iphone, ios, dictionary, ios4, openstreetmap

how to add annotation using map quest, am trying to add annotation using samples provided by map quest.but am not getting it, breaking head since 4 days. Actually I found

```
- (void)addAnnotation:(id <MQAnnotation>)annotation;
```

in `mqmapview.h` ,but `MQAnnotation` is a protocol which contain this method

```
- (void)setCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)aCoord;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, Why do you wanna go for MQMapView instead of MKMapView?

I believe MKMapView is more reliable!!

Comment: because MQMapView doesnt allow turn by turn navigation

Answer (score 0):

```
MQAnnotation *ULannotation = [[MQAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"Current Location" andCoordinate:userLocation];

[mapView addAnnotation:ULannotation];
```

This is how I'm adding annotations with MapQuest.
Initialize and allocate a new `MQAnnotation` with any name you like then just call `addAnnotation` on your `mapview` that you want the annotation added to.